# how to convert row as columns with aggregate function from two or more table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, multiple-tables

I want to get name from station and i will add this name in my aggregate function from train. This is my structure :

Station :

```
CREATE TABLE station
(ID int, Name varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO station
    (ID, Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Luka'),
    (2, 'Lisbon'),
    (3, 'Singapore'),
    (4, 'Banyuwangi'),
    (5, 'Gresik'),
    (6, 'Paris');
```

Train :

```
CREATE TABLE train
    (ID int, Name varchar(100), StationID int, TimeStamp datetime)
;

INSERT INTO train
    (ID, Name,StationID, TimeStamp)
VALUES
    (1, 'Arrived', 1,'2015-01-15 20:31:17.287'),
    (2, 'Go',1,'2015-01-15 20:32:17.287'),
    (3, 'Arrived', 2,'2015-01-16 20:31:17.287'),
    (4, 'Go',2,'2015-01-16 20:32:17.287'),
    (5, 'Arrived', 3,'2015-01-17 20:31:17.287'),
    (6, 'Go',3,'2015-01-17 20:32:17.287'),
    (7, 'Arrived', 4,'2015-01-18 20:31:17.287'),
    (8, 'Go',4,'2015-01-18 20:32:17.287'),
    (9, 'Arrived', 5,'2015-01-19 20:31:17.287'),
    (10, 'Go',5,'2015-01-19 20:32:17.287'),
    (11, 'Arrived', 6,'2015-01-20 20:31:17.287'),
    (12, 'Go',6,'2015-01-20 20:32:17.287')
        ;
```

I want the result like this:

```
Station Name |Arrived  |Time                    |Go | Time
Luka         |Arrived  |2015-01-15 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-15 20:32:17.287
Lisbon       |Arrived  |2015-01-16 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-16 20:32:17.287
Singapore    |Arrived  |2015-01-17 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-17 20:32:17.287
Banyuwangi   |Arrived  |2015-01-18 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-18 20:32:17.287
Gresik       |Arrived  |2015-01-19 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-19 20:32:17.287
Paris        |Arrived  |2015-01-20 20:31:17.287 |Go |2015-01-20 20:32:17.287
```

This is my aggregate query but i just view stationid not the name :

```
select stationid,
max(case when seq = 1 then name end) ARRIVED,
max(case when seq = 1 then timestamp end) TIME,
max(case when seq = 2 then name end) GO,
max(case when seq = 2 then timestamp end) TIME
from
(
    select b.stationid,b.name,b.timestamp,
    row_number() over(partition by b.stationid order by b.name) seq
    from station a, train b
    where  a.id = b.stationid and b.name not like '%reset%'
) schedule
group by stationid
```

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expression

```
WITH C AS(
    select stationid,
    max(case when seq = 1 then name end) ARRIVED,
    max(case when seq = 1 then timestamp end) TIME1,
    max(case when seq = 2 then name end) GO,
    max(case when seq = 2 then timestamp end) TIME2
    from
    (
        select b.stationid,b.name,b.timestamp,
        row_number() over(partition by b.stationid order by b.name) seq
        from station a, train b
        where  a.id = b.stationid and b.name not like '%reset%'
    ) schedule
    group by stationid
)
SELECT station.name, C.ARRIVED, C.TIME1 AS TIME, C.Go, C.TIME2 AS TIME
FROM C INNER JOIN station ON C.stationid = station.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (which is not the best) is adding `name` to `group by` and adding it to the `select`.

```
select stationName,
max(case when seq = 1 then name end) ARRIVED,
max(case when seq = 1 then timestamp end) TIME,
max(case when seq = 2 then name end) GO,
max(case when seq = 2 then timestamp end) TIME
from
(
    select b.stationid,b.name,a.name stationName,b.timestamp,
    row_number() over(partition by b.stationid order by b.name) seq
    from station a, train b
    where  a.id = b.stationid and b.name not like '%reset%'
) schedule
group by stationid, stationName
```

Note that I still keep `stationid` in `group by` for handling repetitive `name`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9723/9)

Comment: Is this like OP requested output?

Comment: @sqluser Which is part is not? OP asked `This is my aggregate query but i just view stationid not the name`

Comment: The query you have written is different from what OP expected.

Comment: @sqluser yes, you are right, there were two name columns and they were messed up, I have changed my query and SQL fiddle,

Comment: @sqluser Thanks for SQL Fiddle link